# How can I transpose only some columns of a table in power query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, transpose

I have a table like this in power query:

| Date | Name | OutputType | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2021 | A | Type1 | 565 | 63521 | 651 | ... |
| 01/10/2021 | A | Type2 | 6546 | 6541 | 13286 | ... |
| 01/10/2021 | B | Type1 | 0 | 5 | 685 | ... |
| 01/10/2021 | B | Type2 | 564 | 0 | 65 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I'm trying to do is "transpose" only the OutputType and Group headers, so that all my groups are in one column, and my OutputTypes become headers. Something like this:

| Date | Name | GroupTypes | Type1 | Type2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2021 | A | Group1 | 541 | 984 |
| 01/10/2021 | A | Group2 | 8971 | 6526 |
| 01/10/2021 | B | Group3 | 321 | 98 |
| 01/10/2021 | B | Group4 | 564 | 845 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried unpivoting the columns, but I get only a partial result, as all my group types do become a single column. But I can't get to "transform" my OutputType values into headers.

Does somebody know how to achieve this in power query?

Sorry if my question is not that clear, my english is not the best.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you not just unpivot the groups, then pivot the output type as the next step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click select the Date, Name and Output Type

Right click Unpivot other columns

Click select the Output Type column

Transform .. pivot column ...  and choose Value as values column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Date", "Name", "OutputType"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[OutputType]), "OutputType", "Value", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```